# django admin search bar based on dropdown attribute

Tags: django, search, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement the search bar in Django admin panel to search in Django admin table. The search bar should have a select attribute drop-down in which I can select an attribute and search for that attribute in my table.
I need something like the below picture.
[image]

I am new to this, Is there any pre-defined library or function I can use in DRF.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late, but I hope it helps.

I am confused between two different search bars that you can use in Django Admin, I am not sure which one you are referring to, so I am adding solutions to both.

If you want to search among the Django Admin table that displays your data, you can use the default `search_field` option that Django itself provides.
The search fields should be a list, not a tuple.

```
class DemoModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
. . .
search_fields = ['title','body','name','other_fields_you_want_to_be_searched']
. . .
```

You can checkout the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/) for more reference

If you want the side filter list that comes with the default `list_filter` attribute to render as a dropdown with a search bar, you can have a look at [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69055082/15747530)