# How to change the Django admin filter to use a dropdown instead of list that can also be searched?

Tags: python, django

Before you mark this as Duplicate, I have read the solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429276/how-to-change-the-django-admin-filter-to-use-a-dropdown-instead-of-list).

In Django Admin I have lots of values. The team that works on that data, currently can use CTRL+F to atleast find the required field.

To fix the UI I have the Dropdown rendering option available in the solution of the question tagged above. But, as I said I need it to be searchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling with the same problem some few weeks back. So this answer might be useful to some developers from the future. 
I managed to solve the problem by writing a custom `template.html`
I have bundled the code in an amazing package now that does the same for you, [here's the link](https://github.com/whoisashish/django-admin-searchable-dropdown).

---

### **Here's how you can implement a Searchable Dropdown in place of the default List:**

**1. Installation:**

```
pip install django-admin-searchable-dropdown
```

This command will install the latest version of the package in your project.
Now, include the package in your project by adding `admin_searchable_dropdown` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` inside `settings.py` file.

**2. Usage:**
Let's say you have following models:

```
from django.db import models

class CarCompany(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class CarModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    company = models.ForeignKey(CarCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And you would like to filter results in `CarModelAdmin` on the basis of `company`. You need to define `search_fields` in `CarCompany` and then define filter like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from admin_searchable_dropdown.filters import AutocompleteFilter


class CarCompanyFilter(AutocompleteFilter):
    title = 'Company' # display title
    field_name = 'company' # name of the foreign key field


class CarCompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name'] # this is required for django's autocomplete functionality
    # ...


class CarModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [CarCompanyFilter]
    # ...
```

---

After following these steps you may see the filter as:

1. [This is how the list filter is rendered in the form of a dropdown when the package is used](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whoisashish/django-admin-searchable-dropdown/main/admin_searchable_dropdown/media/UnFiltered.PNG)
2. [And the dropdown filter is also Searchable](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whoisashish/django-admin-searchable-dropdown/main/admin_searchable_dropdown/media/Filtered.PNG)

### **Features Offered:**

1. If you have large fields in Admin Filter, the sidebar gets widened, this package provides you the same list in a dropdown format, hence, no such hassle.
2. If you have more than, say 20, field items, list filter is now a long side-pane, just ruining the admin interface. The Dropdown filter fixes that.
3. The Dropdown is also "Searchable", with an input text field (which utilizes Django's own `auto_complete` functionailty), so as long as the Django version you are using is greater than 2.0, you should be fine.
4. You can customize other `list_filters` you may have, like change the Title above the dropdown, or a custom Search logic etc.
5. You can customize Widget Texts to display in the Dropdown Option to use something other than the default `str(obj)`